# How to use Vuex mapGetters with Vue 3 SFC Script Setup syntax?

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4, vue-script-setup

I'm refactoring component from regular Vue 3 Composition API to Script Setup syntax. Starting point:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyCoolBareComponent',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('auth', ['isAdmin']),
  },
});
</script>
```

Current [Vue v3 migration documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#notable-new-features), **SFC Composition API Syntax Sugar (< script setup >)**, links to this RFC page: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/182

There is only one example for using computed reactive property:

```
export const computedMsg = computed(() => props.msg + '!!!')
```

As there is no current Vuex 4 documentation available that is mentioning `<scrip setup>`, **it remains unclear to me how I should be using `mapGetters` when using this syntax? Or what is the correct way of going about this with Vuex 4?**

Comment: It is documented now. You don't need to use mapGetters. https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html#accessing-state-and-getters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far this syntax seems to be working. However, I'm hoping that Vuex would develop a cleaner way for exposing computed getters for template.

**If you know a better way, we'd love to hear!**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export const name = 'MyCoolBareComponent';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('user', ['profile', 'roles']),
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

**tldr: scroll down to final result**

There is now better documentation and the simple answer is: You don't need `mapGetters` but you can implement it yourself.

https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html#accessing-state-and-getters

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

const store = useStore()

const count = computed(() => store.getters.count)
</script>
```

If you have many getters you want to turn into a "computed property" you could use something as "intuitive" as this:

```
const { countIsOdd, countIsEven } = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(store.getters).map(getter => [getter, computed(() => store.getters[getter])]))
```

Put that into a function and it even looks nice.

```
const mapGetters = (getters) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(getters).map(getter => [getter, computed(() => getters[getter])]))
}

const { countIsOdd, countIsEven } = mapGetters(store.getters)
```

Put that function into a file and export it as a module...

```
// lib.js
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

const mapGetters = () => {
  const store = useStore()
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(store.getters).map(getter => [getter, computed(() => store.getters[getter])]))
}

export { mapGetters }
```

...and you can easily use it in all your components.

```
// components/MyComponent.vue
<script setup>
import { mapGetters } from '../lib'

const { countIsOdd, countIsEven } = mapGetters()
</script>
```

#### Final result:

Here's the final lib.js I came up with:

```
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

const mapState = () => {
  const store = useStore()
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(store.state).map(
      key => [key, computed(() => store.state[key])]
    )
  )
}

const mapGetters = () => {
  const store = useStore()
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(store.getters).map(
      getter => [getter, computed(() => store.getters[getter])]
    )
  )
}

const mapMutations = () => {
  const store = useStore()
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(store._mutations).map(
      mutation => [mutation, value => store.commit(mutation, value)]
    )
  )
}

const mapActions = () => {
  const store = useStore()
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(store._actions).map(
      action => [action, value => store.dispatch(action, value)]
    )
  )
}

export { mapState, mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions }
```

Using this in the component looks like this:

```
<template>
  Count: {{ count }}
  Odd: {{ counterIsOdd }}
  Even: {{ counterIsEven }}
  <button @click="countUp">count up</button>
  <button @click="countDown">count down</button>
  <button @click="getRemoteCount('https://api.countapi.xyz')">
    get remote count
  </button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from '../lib'

// computed properties
const { count } = mapState()
const { countIsOdd, countIsEvent } = mapGetters()

// commit/dispatch functions
const { countUp, countDown } = mapMutations()
const { getRemoteCount } = mapActions()
</script>
```

Any feedback on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: i really like this solution, i am adapting it to use namespaced modules, but I am in unfamiliar waters... i have figured out how to add the module name to the mapState function, but i am not having any luck getting it to work mapGetters... any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: https://gist.github.com/ub3rb3457/586467f2cbd54d0c96d60e16b247d151  this version allows you to pass the module name as an argument to the map function

Comment: Hey! Glad it was helpful. Don't have time to look into your adaption right now but I will at some point definitely!

Comment: Typescript version: https://gist.github.com/tomscytale/42cd3fca69ac876a6ab185af49815628

Answer (score 3):

```
    import {useStore} from "vuex";
    import {computed} from "vue";
    
    const {getEvents, getSelectedTag} = useStore().getters;
    const events = computed(() => getEvents)
    const selectedTag = computed(() => getSelectedTag)
```

i do this and for me is working

Comment: How would you do this with models? i.e. `mapGetters('user', ['getUserName'])`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to export anything, an SFC will register all variables and components for you and make them available in `template`.

An SFC automatically infers the component's name from its filename.

Here are a few examples that may be useful:

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent'

const store = useStore()

const data = 'Random string as a data'

// without module/data 
const myAction = () => store.dispatch('myAction')
// with data
const mySecondAction = () => store.dispatch('mySecondAction', data)

// with module
const myMutation = () => store.commit('moduleName/myMutation')
// with module/data
const myNewMutation = () => store.commit('moduleName/myNewMutation', data)

const myStateVariable = computed(() => store.state.myStateVariable)
// with module
const myGetter = computed(() => store.getters.moduleName.myGetter)

// replace using of mapState/mapGetters
const state = computed(() => store.state)

// and then
console.log(state.myStateVariable)
console.log(state.mySecondStateVariable)
....

</script>
```

Comment: how is this supposed to work, im getting a linting error `myNewMutation` is assigned but never used. Of course, this is a lambda, where is it supposed to be called?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-usestore-composition-function

Here is an example:

- store.ts

```
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue'
import { createStore, Store } from 'vuex'

// define your typings for the store state
export interface State {
  token: string|null
}

// define injection key
export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol()

export const store = createStore<State>({
  state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') ? localStorage.getItem('token'):'',
  }
})
```

- main.js

```
import { store, key } from './store'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

// pass the injection key
app
.use(store, key)
.mount('#app')
```

- In a vue component

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { key } from './store'

const token = useStore(key) 

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(store.state.token)
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex"
setup() {
  return {
    ...mapGetters("myModule", ["doSomething"])
  }
}
```